# Docker-compose Predis not connection via PHP

Tags: php, nginx, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect PHP with redis using docker (compose)

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.2
  php:
    image: company/php:dev7
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/
    networks:
      - net
    links:
      - redis
  nginx:
    image: company/nginx
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/
      - ./docker/nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - net
    ports:
      - 80:80
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

This all works well and I'm able to run nginx and php. However when I'm trying to connect with Redit it tells me it cannot get the address info:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379] in /var/www/htdocs/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php on line 155

This is the way I'm trying to connect:

```
$client = new \Predis\Client([
    'host'   => 'redis',
]);
```

Also when I look into the redis docker container and look into */etc/hosts* there is no redis hostname. At least I was expecting it over here as I'm trying to link it in the docker-compose.yml.

What do I configure wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot add redis container to `dev` network.

You can update docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.2
    networks:
      - net
  php:
    image: company/php:dev7
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/
    networks:
      - net
  nginx:
    image: company/nginx
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/
      - ./docker/nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - net
    ports:
      - 80:80
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Also, you can omit  container's `links` if you defined `bridge` network.

Also 2. You'll never find linked container IP and hostnames in `hosts` file. Docker use internal DNS service