# PHP Redis connection via Docker - can't connect to redis container (compose setup)

Tags: php, docker, redis, phpredis

I'm trying to establish connection from a HTTP server container to Redis container using phpredis in PHP.

This is the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  arcade:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - HOST_IP=${HOST_IP}
        - XDEBUG_PORT=${XDEBUG_PORT}
    image: arcade-dev:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ../../..:/var/www/localhost/htdocs
    links:
      - marry
    networks:
      - arcade_net
  marry:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=s3cr3t
    volumes:
      - arcade_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - arcade_net
  arcade_cache:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - arcade_cache_data:/data
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - arcade_net
volumes:
  arcade_data: {}
  arcade_cache_data: {}
networks:
  arcade_net:
    driver: bridge
```

This is the Redis client setup:

```
use Redis;

final class ArcadeCache
{

    public static function getClient(): Redis
    {
        $redis = new Redis();
        $redis->connect('arcade_cache');
        return $redis;
    }
}
```

And this is a test I run using phpunit to test the connection

```
public function testRedisConnection(): void
{
    $client = ArcadeCache::getClient();

    $client->append('testKey', 'BAZINGA');
    $bazinga = $client->get('testKey');

    $this->assertEquals('BAZINGA', $bazinga);
}
```

When I run the test (using the image build for the 'arcade' service) I get the following error:

```
RedisException : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
 /opt/project/Infrastructure/ArcadeCache.php:14
 /opt/project/Tests/Infrastructure/ArcadeCacheTest.php:22

 Caused by
 PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Warning: Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

 /opt/project/Infrastructure/ArcadeCache.php:14
 /opt/project/Tests/Infrastructure/ArcadeCacheTest.php:22
```

When I 'exec' to the http server container 'arcade_cache' hostname is properly resolved

```
bash-5.0# ping arcade_cache
PING arcade_cache (172.28.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.28.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.152 ms
64 bytes from 172.28.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
```

When I try to use the IP (`$redis->connect('172.28.0.3');`) instead of hostname connection get's timed out:

```
RedisException : Operation timed out
 /opt/project/Infrastructure/ArcadeCache.php:14
 /opt/project/Tests/Infrastructure/ArcadeCacheTest.php:21

Time: 1.05 minutes, Memory: 6.00 MB

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Connection to DB using 'marry' hostname works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where and how are you running the tests?  (From the host, the Dockerfile, a separate `docker run` command, `docker-compose run`, something else?)

Comment: From PhpStorm - I set the php interpreter to the container built by the compose file (arcade-dev:latest) and right click on the test method or the whole suite and click run test.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `networks`, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212289/docker-compose-predis-not-connection-via-php).

[Off. doc networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something - I am using it the same way. 
Tried also without network specified (by default all containers should be on the same network within compose) - but gives exactly same results.

Besides - pinging between containers works, that's why it puzzles me :)

Comment: You can also delete all of the explicitly declared `networks:` and use the `default` network that Compose provides for you, as discussed in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  The `networks:` declarations in the question are self-consistent and that doesn't seem like the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So for me, when I run tests from inside php container they worked.
My redis connection was this way:

```
redis://redis_user:redis_password@redis:6379
```

the container name of the redis container is `redis`, that is why `@redis:6379` part in the redis config.

But this config did not work when I run the test from **PHPStorm**.
If you have the same problem you can update your redis config this way:

```
redis://redis_user:redis_password@host.docker.internal:6379
```

to also get the tests from PHPStorm work.
With this way both running tests from PHP container and PHPStorm works for me.

By the way I am using Mac device, if you have Linux device you may need to configure your Linux to support `host.docker.internal`